# First line number in lstinputlisting environment

Tags: listings, line-numbering

I use the following code to display line 23-45 of `sort.cpp`:

```
\lstinputlisting[language=C++,linerange=23-45]{sort.cpp}
```

However, the line numbering starts with 1 while I want it start at 23. I found some reference that suggested to change this to

```
\lstinputlisting[language=C++,linerange=23-45,firstnumber=23]{sort.cpp}
```

It works, and I want this to be the default setting. According page 31 of the [`listings` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf),

> **auto** lets the package choose the first number: a new listing starts with
>   number one, a named listing continues the most recent same-named listing
>   (see below), and a stand alone file begins with the number corresponding to
>   the first input line.
>   **last** continues the numbering of the most recent listing and number sets
>   it to the number.

It should be the default. What's wrong here, or am I misundersting the reference?

My listings setting:

```
\usepackage{xcolor,listings}%color support for listings
\lstset{
basicstyle=\footnotesize,
numbers=left, 
numberstyle=\footnotesize, 
keywordstyle=\color{blue!70}, 
commentstyle=\color{red!50!green!50!blue!50}, 
%stringstyle=\ttfamily, % typewriter type for strings
%frame=shadowbox, 
rulesepcolor=\color{red!20!green!20!blue!20},
escapeinside=``, 
xleftmargin=2em,xrightmargin=2em, aboveskip=1em,
breaklines=true             % sets automatic line breaking
}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This default behaviour is understandable since the [`listings` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) has no concern with the layout and/or structure of the imported listing. For that reason, here is one scenario that motivate a separate `firstnumber` key-value that does not default to the first line of `linerange`:  Your `sort.cpp` file has a bunch of unrelated procedures/functions in it. Referencing some of the functions with the line numbers starting with the first element of `linerange` would have no meaning since the line number does not relate to the content.

Though, on a positive note, it is possible to force the `listings` package to make `firstnumber` the same as the first element in `linerange` (called `firstline`) regardless. To do this, we patch the `linerange`-parser (`\lst@GLI@`, short for `G`et `L`ine `I`nterval) using the [`etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) command `\patchcmd`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
...
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\lst@GLI@}% <command>
  {\def\lst@firstline{#1\relax}}% <search>
  {\def\lst@firstline{#1\relax}\def\lst@firstnumber{#1\relax}}% <replace>
  {\typeout{listings firstnumber=firstline}}% <success>
  {\typeout{listings firstnumber not set}}% <failure>
\makeatother
```

The above patch print `listings firstnumber=firstline` if the command `\lst@GLI@` was successfully patched, otherwise it will print `listings firstnumber not set` to the `<jobname>.aux` file. The patch consists of searching for the spot in `\lst@GLI@` where the `firstline` is established, and adds to it an equivalent assignment of the `firstnumber`.

Note, however, that the above patch is a permanent replacement and voids further use of the `firstnumber` key-value.

Comment: Is it possible to patch also directly the first line number of `linerange`? This would still simplify the latex code a lot! Nice patch - thanks.

Comment: @strpeter: I don't understand. How would this work? The premise of the question is to *provide* a fixed `linerange` (the source) and making `firstline` and `firstnumber` (the targets) conform to that. How would fixing the source help?