# Listings line numbers that match the linerange specification

Tags: listings, external-files, line-numbering

This is a follow-up question to [First line number in `lstinputlisting` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26828/5764). Consider the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\usepackage{filecontents,listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{filecontents,listings}
\lstset{
  numbers=left,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize
}
\begin{filecontents*}{mycode.txt}
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26828/5764
%\patchcmd{\lst@GLI@}% <command>
%  {\def\lst@firstline{#1\relax}}% <search>
%  {\def\lst@firstline{#1\relax}\def\lst@firstnumber{#1\relax}}% <replace>
%  {\typeout{listings firstnumber=firstline}}% <success>
%  {\typeout{listings firstnumber not set}}% <failure>
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[linerange={1-3}]{mycode.txt}
\lstinputlisting[linerange={2-4}]{mycode.txt}
\lstinputlisting[linerange={2-2,4-5}]{mycode.txt}
\end{document}
```

*Without* the aid of the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) patch (or the default), the output looks like that of the leftmost column. *With* the aid of the patch (a "`firstnumber` correction), the output looks like that of the middle side. However, I'd like the output to look like that of the rightmost column.

[image]

That is, the eventual output of line numbers should match that of the `linerange` specification.

<sub>The trivial solution I'm hoping to avoid is the inclusion of separate `\lstinputlisting`s for each range with the appropriate vertical adjustment of `-2\medskipamount` (default space above/below an included listing). That was how the rightmost column was obtained in the first place.</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My previous solution had problems with the numbering of blank lines.  I have added a new solution and kept the old one further down.

## New Solution

What one really needs to do is reset the counter `lstnumber` at the beginning of each range.  To achieve this one needs to hook into an internal command `\lst@SkipToFirst`.  One approach is to define a new key `matchrangestart` initialised as false via

```
\lst@Key{matchrangestart}{f}{\lstKV@SetIf{#1}\lst@ifmatchrangestart}
```

and then add the following test at the beginning of `\lst@SkiptoFirst`:

```
\lst@ifmatchrangestart\c@lstnumber=\numexpr-1+\lst@firstline\fi
```

This the general way `listings` set-up keys with true/false values and how it handles the counter `lstnumber`.  This code says if the `matchrangestart` key is true then when skipping forward to the beginning of a rang set `lstnumber` to one less than the first line number of the range.  When the line gets printed this number is then incremented before being printed so we get the desired output.

[image: New sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents,listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize
}

\begin{filecontents*}{mycode.txt}
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3


Line 6
Line 7

Line 9
Line 10
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter
\lst@Key{matchrangestart}{f}{\lstKV@SetIf{#1}\lst@ifmatchrangestart}
\def\lst@SkipToFirst{%
    \lst@ifmatchrangestart\c@lstnumber=\numexpr-1+\lst@firstline\fi
    \ifnum \lst@lineno<\lst@firstline
        \def\lst@next{\lst@BeginDropInput\lst@Pmode
        \lst@Let{13}\lst@MSkipToFirst
        \lst@Let{10}\lst@MSkipToFirst}%
        \expandafter\lst@next
    \else
        \expandafter\lst@BOLGobble
    \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
  Standard
  \lstset{numbers=left}
  \lstinputlisting[linerange={1-3}]{mycode.txt}

  \lstinputlisting[linerange={2-6}]{mycode.txt}

  \lstinputlisting[linerange={2-2,4-6,8-9}]{mycode.txt}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
  Literal
  \lstset{numbers=left,matchrangestart=t}
  \lstinputlisting[linerange={1-3}]{mycode.txt}

  \lstinputlisting[linerange={2-6}]{mycode.txt}

  \lstinputlisting[linerange={2-2,4-6,8-9}]{mycode.txt}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

## Old Solution

*This places wrong numbers on blank lines*

The `listings` package has an internal plain counter `\lst@lineno` holding the line number you are after.  Now the `numbers=left` option, runs the code

```
\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\llap{\normalfont
                \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}\kern\lst@numbersep}}
```

so all we need to do is take this code and replace the printed latex counter `\thelstnumber` by `\the\list@lineno`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents,listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize
}

\begin{filecontents*}{mycode.txt}
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
\end{filecontents*}

\makeatletter
\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\llap{\normalfont
                \lst@numberstyle{\the\lst@lineno}\kern\lst@numbersep}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[linerange={1-3}]{mycode.txt}
\lstinputlisting[linerange={2-4}]{mycode.txt}
\lstinputlisting[linerange={2-2,4-5}]{mycode.txt}
\end{document}
```

The above coding sets this style globally.  If you wish to have local switches then you can extend the `listings` definition of the `numbers` option, adding a `leftliteral` type as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents,listings}

\makeatletter
\lst@Key{numbers}{none}{%
    \let\lst@PlaceNumber\@empty
    \lstKV@SwitchCases{#1}%
    {none&\\%
     left&\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\llap{\normalfont
                \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}\kern\lst@numbersep}}\\%
     leftliteral&\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\llap{\normalfont
                \lst@numberstyle{\the\lst@lineno}\kern\lst@numbersep}}\\%
     right&\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\rlap{\normalfont
                \kern\linewidth \kern\lst@numbersep
                \lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}}}%
    }{\PackageError{Listings}{Numbers #1 unknown}\@ehc}}
\makeatother

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize
}

\begin{filecontents*}{mycode.txt}
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
  Standard
  \lstset{numbers=left}
  \lstinputlisting[linerange={1-3}]{mycode.txt}
  \lstinputlisting[linerange={2-4}]{mycode.txt}
  \lstinputlisting[linerange={2-2,4-5}]{mycode.txt}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
  Literal
  \lstset{numbers=leftliteral}
  \lstinputlisting[linerange={1-3}]{mycode.txt}
  \lstinputlisting[linerange={2-4}]{mycode.txt}
  \lstinputlisting[linerange={2-2,4-5}]{mycode.txt}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
  Standard
  \lstset{numbers=left}
  \lstinputlisting[linerange={1-3}]{mycode.txt}
  \lstinputlisting[linerange={2-4}]{mycode.txt}
  \lstinputlisting[linerange={2-2,4-5}]{mycode.txt}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample switch]

Comment: Well, that was easy! `:)` Thanks Andrew.

Comment: This seems to overwrite other listingsoptions set by `lstset` like `showlines=true`– is there a way to keep those as well?

Comment: @K.Stm. It is not overwriting these options, but there is interaction with them that one may not wish.  The problem is that different options reference different counters.

Comment: @AndrewSwann True. I’m having problems with `showlines` that are unrelated. However, the solution here doesn’t go nicely with the `lstlinebgrd` package. If one wants to keep background colors, one has to imitate its implementation and add `\lst@linebgrd` between the last two closing curly braces in the definitions of the key cases `left`, `leftliteral`, `right` (and `rightliteral` if one has defined it), e.g. `…\kern\lst@numbersep}\lst@linebgrd}\\%`.

Comment: @K.Stm. Not surprising; that package is also changing the same command.  Your code suggestion seems to be the right sort approach.  If you have open problems, you should ask a separate question on this site.

Comment: @AndrewSwann The code fails when the there is a blank line in the file being input. If there is something like, Line 5, Blank line 6, Line 7, the line numbers displayed are 5,7,7. Any suggestion how can this  be remedied? I found this answer while looking for the feature presented and it saved my day, well almost.

Comment: @Masroor Thank you for pointing that out.  I have posted an new solution that requires a little more intervention, but seems to do the job.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thanks a lot, and yes, it works, flawlessly, in terms of my short term testing. Since I plan to use this one heavily  for a course slide in this semester, I hope I will be able to keep you posted of further issues, if any. Just one small comment, don't you think that it would have been better to pack these two, `numbers=left,matchrangestart=t` inside `numbers=leftliteral`? You seem to have completely taken out the  `leftliteral` switch. Is it not it going to create compatibility issues with existing documents? As a personal note, I particularly liked those words in the switch.

Comment: @Masroor I introduced `matchrangestart` as this a feature orthogonal to placing of numbers.  It works equally well with `numbers=right`.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Oh, I get your point. I can live with slightly editing my existing documents which are not many yet.

Answer (score 5):

Based upon [Andrew's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110195/28879) I found this to be a better match to the problem:

```
\makeatletter
\def\lst@MSkipToFirst{%
    \global\advance\lst@lineno\@ne
    \ifnum \lst@lineno=\lst@firstline
        \def\lst@next{\lst@LeaveMode \global\lst@newlines\z@
        \lst@OnceAtEOL \global\let\lst@OnceAtEOL\@empty
        \lst@InitLstNumber % Added to work with modified \lsthk@PreInit.
        \lsthk@InitVarsBOL
        \c@lstnumber=\numexpr-1+\lst@lineno % this enforces the displayed line numbers to always be the input line numbers
        \lst@BOLGobble}%
        \expandafter\lst@next
    \fi}
\makeatother
```

The advantage over his answer is that it supports multi-range constructs correctly without the need to introduce a key. This is done by overriding the method which actually takes care of range-skipping and already containing a hook for the first line of a new range.

Tested against listings 1.6 (2015/06/04). As always when overriding a function pay attention to changes of the package's source (shouldn't be to hard as only one line was added).

## Bonus:

2mm whitespace between line-blocks:

```
\makeatletter
\def\lst@MSkipToFirst{%
    \global\advance\lst@lineno\@ne
    \ifnum \lst@lineno=\lst@firstline
        \def\lst@next{\lst@LeaveMode \global\lst@newlines\z@
        \lst@OnceAtEOL \global\let\lst@OnceAtEOL\@empty
        \ifnum \c@lstnumber>0
            \vspace{2 mm}
        \fi
        \lst@InitLstNumber % Added to work with modified \lsthk@PreInit.
        \lsthk@InitVarsBOL
        \c@lstnumber=\numexpr-1+\lst@lineno % this enforces the displayed line numbers to always be the input line numbers
        \lst@BOLGobble}%
        \expandafter\lst@next
    \fi}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Based on your answer I replaced the whitespace with a more visible dashed line: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/700722/74295