# How to skip line numbering on the first line with lstlistings

Tags: listings

I need help for lstlistings. I have a code that start with:

```
INPUT: c, m
rest of code...
```

I want that the first line doesn't view the number line.
This is my lstset:

```
\lstset{language=Java,
 numberstyle=\scriptsize,
 numbers=left,
 numbersep=5pt,
 numberblanklines=false,
 captionpos=b,
 basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
        columns=fullflexible,
        xleftmargin=16pt,
        frame=leftline,
 breaklines=true,
 tabsize=2,
 prebreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
        escapeinside={$}{$}
}
```

Someone can help me please?

Comment: Related: [`listings` line numbers that match the `linerange` specification](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110187/5764)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem. Also, I'd recommend you include the input and the desired output (it is not clear from your description).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) provides the key-value `numberfirstline` (set to `false` by default), it doesn't seem to deliver on the promise of not numbering the first line. As such, the following is work-around: Start "numbering" from 0 and check when printing the number whether it should be printed or not using a conditional.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  numberstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  %numberfirstline=false,
  firstnumber=0,
  numbers=left
}
\makeatletter
\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\ifnum\value{lstnumber}=0\else
  \llap{\normalfont\lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}\kern\lst@numbersep}\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
INPUT: c, m
rest of code...
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

If placement of the number is to the right (using `numbers=right`), then the following redefinition of `\lst@PlaceNumber` is required:

```
\makeatletter
\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\ifnum\value{lstnumber}=0\else
  \rlap{\normalfont\kern\linewidth \kern\lst@numbersep\lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}}\fi}
\makeatother
```

Note that these redefinitions of `\lst@PlaceNumber` should occur *after* setting the `numbers` option.

Comment: Can you hide line numbers from the first three line, for instance? Is there any way to generalize your solution?

Comment: @Ido: Try with `\ifnum\value{lstnumber}<2\else ... \fi`.

Answer (score 3):

Add `firstline=2` in the `\lstset`.

```
\lstset{language=Java,
 firstline=2,
 numberstyle=\scriptsize,
 numbers=left,
 numbersep=5pt,
 numberblanklines=false,
 captionpos=b,
 basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
        columns=fullflexible,
        xleftmargin=16pt,
        frame=leftline,
 breaklines=true,
 tabsize=2,
 prebreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\hookleftarrow}},
        escapeinside={$}{$}
}
```

Comment: This will ignore the first line entirely, while the OP seems to be interested in just having it not numbered.