# Listings: Skip line number on current line

Tags: listings, line-numbering

So I am trying to use the listings package to show some source code.
However I would like to be able to skip line numbers for certain lines, such that the do not receive any line number, but does not increment the line number either. 
It is very similar to this: [Suppress line numbering for specific lines in listings package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34094/suppress-line-numbering-for-specific-lines-in-listings-package)

except that I need to be able to suppress the first line. SOmething like this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}
|\Suppressnumber|First line.|\Reactivatenumber| % ONLY SKIP LINE NUMBER ON THIS LINE!
Second line. % START WITH LINE NUMBER 1 HERE
Third line.
Next line.
Next Line
\end{lstlisting}.
```

How do I change this command:

```
\lstset{numbers=left,numberblanklines=false,escapeinside=||}
\let\origthelstnumber\thelstnumber
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\Suppressnumber{%
  \lst@AddToHook{OnNewLine}{%
    \let\thelstnumber\relax%
     \advance\c@lstnumber-\@ne\relax%
    }%
}

\newcommand*\Reactivatenumber{%
  \lst@AddToHook{OnNewLine}{%
   \let\thelstnumber\origthelstnumber%
   \advance\c@lstnumber\@ne\relax}%
}
```

So it works like I want?

For others with the same issue, currently I am using [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203199/how-to-skip-first-line-lstlistings) solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  numberstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  %numberfirstline=false,
  firstnumber=0,
  numbers=left
}
\makeatletter
\def\lst@PlaceNumber{\ifnum\value{lstnumber}=0\else
  \llap{\normalfont\lst@numberstyle{\thelstnumber}\kern\lst@numbersep}\fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
INPUT: c, m
rest of code...
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commands `\Suppressnumber` on `\Reactivatenumber` from the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34094/suppress-line-numbering-for-specific-lines-in-listings-package) you mentioned can be used and no change is needed. You just have to call `\Suppressnumber` before the `\begin{lstlisting}`.

Example:

```
\Suppressnumber
\begin{lstlisting}
    First line.|\Reactivatenumber| % NO ON THIS LINE!
    Second line. % START WITH LINE NUMBER 1 HERE
    Third line.
    Next line.
    Next Line
\end{lstlisting}
```