# Listings skip line numbers cause already defined warning

Tags: hyperref, listings, line-numbering

I use listings and hyperref for a project where I want to skip line numbers on some listings. I'm using a `\Suppressnumber`-command a `\Reactivatenumber`-command (from [Listings: Skip line number on current line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278055/listings-skip-line-number-on-current-line])). However, the `\Suppressnumber`-command produces the following error

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{lstnumber.-1.\\thelstnumber\040}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
```

It also produces this warning for all subsequent listings including input and inline listings. For my project it means 60000 lines (out of 63000) in the log. 
What can I do to fix it?

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=[Sharp]C,escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}}

\let\origthelstnumber\thelstnumber
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\Suppressnumber{%
    \lst@AddToHook{OnNewLine}{%
        \let\thelstnumber\relax%
        \advance\c@lstnumber-\@ne\relax%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
   \begin{lstlisting}
       public void Main(){
           (*@ \Suppressnumber @*)
           int i = 0;
       }
   \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your code works fine for me

Comment: It compiles. But if you check the *.log-file, you will see a ```destination with the same identifier```-warning which just accumulates and produce an insane amount of log.

Comment: You should edit the question and state that it's not an error but a log warning: I did not understand that and thought it was a compilation error :)